# redirigir la salida de una funcion a la impresora en python

Tags: python

estoy empezando en Python, y para aprender, me he empeñado en crear una aplicación para crear tarjetas identificativas, viendo tutoriales y manuales, he conseguido leer/escribir en SQLITE, y desde aquí, poder ver datos con Tkinter.
He creado una función, que es la tarjeta identificativa con los datos del registro, foto del usuario y una imagen para el fondo, la tarjeta sale perfectamente por pantalla, pero no soy capaz de enviarla hacia una impresora.
Esta es la función:

```
def imprimir_tarjeta(self):
    self.fondo1=PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/antonio/Desktop/Ejercicios/Tar_personal/Fotos/Fondo25.gif")
    self.lblFondo1=Label(self.ventana,image=self.fondo1).place(x=700,y=0) #fondo

    self.labelf = Label(self.ventana,image=self.imagen, bd=0)
    self.labelf.place(x=720, y=10, width=125, height=190)


    self.label23=Label(self.ventana, bg="#ffffff", font=('', 18, 'bold'), textvariable=self.nombre, width=30, anchor='center')
    self.label23.place(x=860, y=30)

    self.label23=Label(self.ventana, bg="#ffffff", font=('', 18, 'bold'), textvariable=self.categoria,width=30, anchor='center')
    self.label23.place(x=860, y=100)

    self.label24=Label(self.ventana, bg="#ffffff", font=('', 18, 'bold'), textvariable=self.cargo,width=30, anchor='center')
    self.label24.place(x=860, y=170)
```

He mirado por internet, pero todo lo que veo es sobre imprimir texto, no he encontrado imprimir imágenes en color con textos, la idea sería que la salida, envés de ir a pantalla que sea impresora.

¿Me podéis ayudar?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: aqui hay un articulo en ingles que te puede servir solo basta con traducir http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Comment: Muchas gracias Bryro, le echaré un vistazo. Si consigo lo que quiero ya os informaré.